# Lotus Notes: How to export the view (column values) in .xls instead of .csv

Tags: excel, csv, lotus-notes, notesview

I would like to export the CSVview based from column values in .xls format instead of .csv format. Right now it exports in .csv. I tried replacing the filename to .xls but the file won't open to both MS Excel and Open Office. Could you please help?

Here is the code:

```html
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim CSVview As NotesView    
    Dim lookupview As NotesView 
    Dim exportmaildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim pathdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim object As NotesEmbeddedObject
    Dim exporttoid As Variant
    Dim datafileName As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filenames As Variant

    Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
    Set CSVview=db.GetView("Top10DCV")

    datafileEnd$ = "ESI_Top_10_Density_Offenders.csv"

    Set lookupview = db.GetView("lookupkeyword")    
    Set pathdoc = lookupview.GetDocumentByKey("UploadFilePath")
    If Not pathdoc Is Nothing Then
        filepath = pathdoc.Keyword(0)
        datafileName =  filepath & datafileEnd$
    Else
        MsgBox "File path not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    datafileNum = FreeFile()
    Open datafileName For Output As datafileNum

    Call ViewCSVPrint ( CSVview, datafileName )

    Set exportmaildoc = lookupview.GetDocumentByKey("Density")

    If Not exportmaildoc Is Nothing Then
        exporttoid = exportmaildoc.Keyword
    End If
    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Set maildoc = db.CreateDocument
    Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
    maildoc.subject = "Report export file"
        Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(maildoc, "Body" )        
        Call rtitem.AppendText("Please find the report below:" )
        Call rtitem.AddNewLine( 2 ) 
        Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject( EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", datafileName)
    Dim allofthem() As String
    ReDim Preserve allofthem(UBound(exporttoid)) As String
    For q = 0 To UBound(exporttoid)
        allentries = allentries + 1
        allofthem(q) = exporttoid(q)
    Next
    maildoc.sendto = allofthem
    If maildoc.sendto(0) <> "" Then
        Call maildoc.send(False)                        
    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub  ViewCSVPrint (CSVview As NotesView, FileName As String )

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim vc As NotesViewEntryCollection

    'CSV Static Headers
    Print #datafileNum%,(Format$("DimWt/ActWt%","")&";"&Format$("DimWt-ActWt","")&";"&Format$("MT/PN","")& ";"&Format$("Model","")&";"&Format$("PkgVol/ProdVol","")&";"&Format$("PkgProdL(mm)","")& ";"&Format$("PkgProdW(mm)","")& ";"&Format$("PkgProdD(mm)","")&";"&Format$("PkgProdVol(CubicMeters)","")&";"&Format$("PkgProdWt(kg)","")& ";"&Format$("PkgProdDimWt","")& ";"&Format$("ProdL(OD)mm","")&";"&Format$("ProdW(OD)mm","")&";"&Format$("ProdD(OD)mm","")& ";"&Format$("ProdVol(CubicMeters)","")& ";"&Format$("ProdWt(kg)","")&";"&Format$("ProdDensity","")&";"&Format$("PkgProdDensity","")&";"&Format$("Pkg/ProdVolRatio",""))

    Const NotesMacro$ = {@DBColumn("":"";@dbname;"Top10DCV";2)}
    retval = Evaluate(NotesMacro$)
    For t = 0 To UBound(retval)
        Set vc = CSVview.GetAllEntriesByKey(retval(t), True)
        Set v2entry = vc.GetFirstEntry
        doccount1 = 0

        Do While doccount1 < 10 And Not v2entry Is Nothing

            ReDim Preserve tmpArray3(tmpcount3)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray4(tmpcount4)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray5(tmpcount5)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray6(tmpcount6)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray7(tmpcount7)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray8(tmpcount8)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray9(tmpcount9)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray10(tmpcount10)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray11(tmpcount11)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray12(tmpcount12)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray13(tmpcount13)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray14(tmpcount14)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray15(tmpcount15)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray16(tmpcount16)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray17(tmpcount17)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray18(tmpcount18)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray19(tmpcount19)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray20(tmpcount20)
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray21(tmpcount21)

            tmpArray3(tmpcount3) = v2entry.ColumnValues(3)
            tmpArray4(tmpcount4) = v2entry.ColumnValues(4)
            tmpArray5(tmpcount5) = v2entry.ColumnValues(5)
            tmpArray6(tmpcount6) = v2entry.ColumnValues(6)
            tmpArray7(tmpcount7) = v2entry.ColumnValues(7)
            tmpArray8(tmpcount8) = v2entry.ColumnValues(8)
            tmpArray9(tmpcount9) = v2entry.ColumnValues(9)
            tmpArray10(tmpcount10) = v2entry.ColumnValues(10)
            tmpArray11(tmpcount11) = v2entry.ColumnValues(11)
            tmpArray12(tmpcount12) = v2entry.ColumnValues(12)
            tmpArray13(tmpcount13)= v2entry.ColumnValues(13)
            tmpArray14(tmpcount14)= v2entry.ColumnValues(14)
            tmpArray15(tmpcount15)= v2entry.ColumnValues(15)
            tmpArray16(tmpcount16)= v2entry.ColumnValues(16)
            tmpArray17(tmpcount17)= v2entry.ColumnValues(17)
            tmpArray18(tmpcount18)= v2entry.ColumnValues(18)
            tmpArray19(tmpcount19)= v2entry.ColumnValues(19)
            tmpArray20(tmpcount20)= v2entry.ColumnValues(20)
            tmpArray21(tmpcount21)= v2entry.ColumnValues(21)


            doccount1 = doccount1 + 1

            Print #datafileNum%,(Format$(tmpArray3(tmpcount3),"0.00%")&";"&Format$(tmpArray4(tmpcount4),"0.00") & ";" & tmpArray5(tmpcount5) & ";" & tmpArray6(tmpcount6) & ";" & Format$(tmpArray7(tmpcount7),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray8(tmpcount8),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray9(tmpcount9),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray10(tmpcount10),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray11(tmpcount11),"0.000")&";"&Format$(tmpArray12(tmpcount12),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray13(tmpcount13),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray14(tmpcount14),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray15(tmpcount15),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray16(tmpcount16),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray17(tmpcount17),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray18(tmpcount18),"0.0")&";"&Format$(tmpArray19(tmpcount19),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray20(tmpcount20),"0.00")&";"&Format$(tmpArray21(tmpcount21),"0.00"))

            Set v2entry = vc.GetNextEntry(v2entry)


            tmpcount3=tmpcount3 + 1
            tmpcount4=tmpcount4 + 1
            tmpcount5=tmpcount5 + 1
            tmpcount6=tmpcount6 + 1
            tmpcount7=tmpcount7 + 1
            tmpcount8=tmpcount8 + 1
            tmpcount9=tmpcount9 + 1
            tmpcount10=tmpcount10 + 1
            tmpcount11=tmpcount11 + 1
            tmpcount12=tmpcount12 + 1
            tmpcount13=tmpcount13 + 1
            tmpcount14=tmpcount14 + 1
            tmpcount15=tmpcount15 + 1
            tmpcount16=tmpcount16 + 1
            tmpcount17=tmpcount17 + 1
            tmpcount18=tmpcount18 + 1
            tmpcount19=tmpcount19 + 1
            tmpcount20=tmpcount20 + 1
            tmpcount21=tmpcount21 + 1

        Loop
    Next
    Close datafileNum%
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a HTML table, but set the file extension to .xls instead.
I blogged about it here: http://blog.texasswede.com/export-from-notes-to-excel-3-different-ways/
And here: http://blog.texasswede.com/generate-excel-spreadsheets-using-lotusscript/

Finally you can use a class I posted on my blog:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

Here is the code to export a view to HTML for import into Excel:

```
Dim csv As CSVData
Dim outfile As String

Set csv = New CSVData("DominoServer/YourDomain", "names.nsf", "People\By Last Name")
'*** Create HTML table and save as .xls to open in Excel
outfile = "c:\ExcelExportTest.xls"
Open outfile For Output As #1
Print #1, "<table>"
ForAll row In csv.HTMLArray()
    Print #1, row
End ForAll
Print #1, "</table>"
Close #1
```

And below is the class itself. It also let you export the view as CSV as a bonus.

```
%REM
    Agent View Export
    Created Mar 27, 2013 by Karl-Henry Martinsson
    Description: Code to export a specified view as CSV.
    Copyright (c) 2013 by Karl-Henry Martinsson
    This code is distributed under the terms of 
    the Apache Licence Version 2. 
    See http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
%END REM

Option Public
Option Declare

Class RowData
    Public column List As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetColumnHeader(view As NotesView)
        Dim viewcolumn As NotesViewColumn
        Dim cnt As Integer
        ForAll vc In view.Columns
            Set viewcolumn = vc
            column(CStr(cnt)) = viewcolumn.Title 
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End Forall  
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetColumnValues(values As Variant)
        Dim cnt As Integer
        Dim tmp As String 
        ForAll v In values
            If IsArray(v) Then
                ForAll c In v
                    tmp = tmp + c + Chr$(13)
                End ForAll
                column(CStr(cnt)) = Left$(tmp,Len(tmp)-1)
            Else
                column(CStr(cnt)) = v 
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll          
    End Sub
End Class

Class CSVData
    Private row List As RowData
    Private rowcnt As Long

    %REM
        Function New
        Description: Open the view and read view data 
        into a list of RowData objects.
    %END REM    
    Public Sub New(server As String, database As String, viewname As String)
        Dim db As NotesDatabase
        Dim view As NotesView
        Dim col As NotesViewEntryCollection
        Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
        Dim colcnt As Integer

        Set db = New NotesDatabase(server, database)
        If db Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not open " + database + " on " + server,16,"Error" 
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set view = db.GetView(viewname)
        If view Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not access view " + viewname + ".",16,"Error" 
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set col = view.AllEntries()
        rowcnt = 0
        Set entry = col.GetFirstEntry()
        Set row("Header") = New RowData()
        Call row("Header").SetColumnHeader(view)
        Do Until entry Is Nothing
            rowcnt = rowcnt + 1
            Set row(CStr(rowcnt)) = New RowData()
            Call row(CStr(rowcnt)).SetColumnValues(entry.ColumnValues)
            Set entry = col.GetNextEntry(entry) 
        Loop
    End Sub

    %REM
        Function CSVArray
        Description: Returns a string array of CSV data by row
    %END REM
    Public Function CSVArray() As Variant
        Dim rowarray() As String 
        Dim textrow As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        ReDim rowarray(rowcnt) As String

        ForAll r In row
            textrow = ""
            ForAll h In r.column 
                textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |",|
            End ForAll
            rowarray(cnt) = Left$(textrow,Len(textrow)-1)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
        CSVArray = rowarray
    End Function

    %REM
        Function HTMLArray
        Description: Returns a string array of HTML data by row
    %END REM
Public Function HTMLArray() As Variant
        Dim rowarray() As String 
        Dim textrow As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        ReDim rowarray(rowcnt) As String

        ForAll r In row
            textrow = ""
            ForAll h In r.column 
                textrow = textrow + |<td>| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"<br>") + |</td>|
            End ForAll
            rowarray(cnt) = "<tr>" + textrow + "</tr>"
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
        HTMLArray = rowarray
    End Function

End Class
```